# Accessing python generators in parallel using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, parallel-processing, generator

I have a Python generator which pulls in a pretty huge table from a data warehouse. After pulling in the data, I am processing the data using celery in a distributed manner. After testing I realized the the generator is the bottleneck. It can't produce enough tasks for celery workers to work on. This is when I have decided to optimize my python generator.

**More details on the generator**

The generator hits the data warehouse with chunk queries and these query results are basically independent of each other and stateless. So I thought this is a good candidate for making it parallel using the `multiprocessing` module. I looked around how to parallelize generators fetch without much direction.

So if my Python generator generates stateless chunks of data, this should be a good candidate for multiprocessing right? Are there any ways to parallelize python generators? Also are there any side effects which I should be aware of using parallelism in Python generators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be trying to solve this problem at the wrong level of abstraction. Python generators are inherently stateful, and thus you can't split a generator across processes without some form of synchronization, and that will kill any performance gains that you might achieve through parallelism. I would recommend instead creating separate generators for each process and having them start at some offset from each other.

For example if you have 4 processes, you basically have the first process handle the first chunk and then it process the 5th chunk followed by the 9th chunk and so on adding N where N is the number of processes that you've setup. This requires you to hand off a unique index to each of the processes at startup.